# C# LINQ group and count questions

Tags: c#, linq

I have the below query that groups up a bunch of printers and then calculates their downtime. What I would like to do is get how many printers are in each group. I'm not sure if I need to run two query or could I accomplish this in one?

Query:

```
var records = (from r in SharePoint.Records
    group r by new
    {
        Printer = getValue(r.Values["ows_printer_id_x003a_Device"]),
    } into g
    select new
    {
        Printers = g.Key.Printer,
        CurrentHours = g.Sum(x => getDownTime(x.Values["ows_Downtime"])),
        //  Total = g.Count()
        //CTDHours = g.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("CurrentHours") + x.Field<int>("CTDHours"))
    });
```

Comment: maybe add to the new 'count = g.Sum(x=>1);'

Comment: Have you tried just uncommenting that total line? Is Count not working?

Comment: What is wrong with `Total = g.Count()`, that should work.

Comment: I don't understand. There is only one printer in each group (it is the key). How do you want to count them?

Comment: @Ben my bad I didn't loop all the way through record set , your right that did work, please post that as your answer and I will give you credit for it.

Comment: @Mike Well yeah, because you only have one printer per group. What is the common attribute you want to group the printers *by*?

Comment: Your count is `g.Count()`

Comment: @Asad, n sorry I was answering @Ben."g.Count()" works I had a error in my code that I did not catch.

Comment: @Asad What makes you think there is only one printer per group? If records has 2 items where "ows_printer_id_x003a_Device" = "SomePrinter", then `g.Count()` will be 2.

Comment: @BenRobinson If there are multiple records where the `Printer` is `ows_printer_id_etc`, then they'll be grouped together into a group with *1 printer* (ows_printer_id_etc) as the key, and a bunch of records relating to that printer as the members of the group. I think it's pretty clear that if you're grouping by printer, you're not going to have more than one printer per group.

Comment: @Asad Yes all the items in the group will have the same printer, I understood you to mean there will not be more than one item in the group with the same printer, as you were questioning how you would count them, perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: @BenRobinson No worries. I was going by what the OP said in the question here: "What I would like to do is get how many printers are in each group." If this is actually what the OP wants to determine, the answer is always 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var records = (from r in SharePoint.Records
    group r by new
    {
        Printer = getValue(r.Values["ows_printer_id_x003a_Device"]),
    } into g
    select new
    {
        Printers = g.Key.Printer,
        CurrentHours = g.Sum(x => getDownTime(x.Values["ows_Downtime"])),
        Total = g.Count()
    });
```

`Total = g.Count` should work.

I'm curious why you're using `getValue()` here and I think that's where your problem might be.  Doesn't `Printer = r.ows_printer_id_x003a_Device` work?  Have you verified the data in the "ows_printer_id_x003a_Device" member, and does that part of the query produce the groupings you want?  Try using LinqPad to break it down.

Comment: Yes it does, but I uses Printer to display the printer name the getValue (custom method) is there because SharePoint adds extra stuff in the data field. I have no idea why it does that but it does, getvalues just cleans that up and returns me the true value.

Comment: Ah I see; I'm used to working with Linq to Entities (to MS SQL) so such shenanigans are not allowed.  You can only use functions which can be converted to T-SQL in that environment since the entire query is interpreted and send to the db server.